# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: android, json, kotlin

i have tries many suggestions from other same questions but does not help, how can i run this test successfully:

```
@Test
fun isJsonCorrectPersonConvert() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val json = gson.toJson("[{\"Id\":2,\"Text\":\"Математика\"},{\"Id\":5,\"Text\":\"Физика\"}]")
    val results = gson.fromJson(json, Array<Person>::class.java)
    Assert.assertNotNull(results)
    Assert.assertNotNull(results[0].Id)
    Assert.assertNotNull(results[0].Text)
    System.out.println(results.toString())
}

data class Person(val Id: Int,val Text:String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
val json: String = "[{\"Id\":2,\"Text\":\"Математика\"},{\"Id\":5,\"Text\":\"Физика\"}]"
val results: List<Person> = gson.fromJson(json , Array<Person>::class.java).toList()
```